# ADFS MFA throws Error for some Users/Client PCs

Tags: adfs, windows-server-2012-r2

We have a standard ADFS Server for Office 356. I created now a MVC Intranet/Page that i secure also via ADFS. For the ADFS i have written two MFA Providers, one with SMS and one with TOTP. All is up and running. 
Login is okay for all Users, but the MFA (StepUp Auth for some Pages) fails for some users or some machines sometimes. (randomly they work or dont)

An error (thrown by ADFS) will look in the clients browser like this:

*Activity ID: 00000000-0000-0000-c82a-0080010000d3
    Relying party: Portal
    Error time: Wed, 07 Jun 2017 14:08:56 GMT
    Cookie: enabled
    User agent string: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:53.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/53.0*

or this:

*Activity ID: 00000000-0000-0000-e525-0080000000fb
    Relying party: Portal Developer
    Error time: Fri, 02 Jun 2017 13:53:47 GMT
    Cookie: enabled
    User agent string: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; Trident/8.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; .NET CLR 3.5.30729)*

I have activated the ADFS Trace/Debug Log. Unfortunatly i cant find any errors in the EventVwr on the ADFS Server.
Any Ideas what i can do?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.
I fugured now out, that have more than one ADFS Server. I had the MFA Provider installed on only one Server.
On the Second ADFS Server the Log, with the Errors, and everything is there.
Sorry. And sorry to myself.